# Asp.net core login Identity template is it safe to use?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I am new is asp.net core

I am trying to create web application using asp.net core 3.1 as per the instruction on [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

i created login page which is working, application login is working. so after login 1st user in application i copied the cookies of 1st user to other browser and open localhost site and i saw user got loggedin without authentication.

is this right implementation how to create safe login and authorization module in asp.net core webapp

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        // Add Distributed Redis Cache for Session
        

      
        services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
        {
            options.Configuration = "localhost";
            options.InstanceName = "Session_";
        });
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // 20 minutes later from last access your session will be removed.
                           
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
       
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        // Adds session middleware to pipeline
       
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

sample code from [link](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/identity/sample)

Comment: that's just how it works. If you copy the auth cookie from any site, it will work like that. That's why cookies should never be accessible to javascript for example, to avoid malicious script from capturing cookies

Comment: Let say in orgnization many  user have different access if any user got access to admn user cookie and if i manually copy it then he will get admin access. is there any way to protect or to authenticate cookie which i issued to original browser

Comment: the best thing you can do, is to enforce HTTPS when project is in production.

Comment: @YegorAndrosov that will not solve the problem

Comment: i don't see problem in your question which should be solved. You can't protect cookie from being stolen, it is job of the browser and your operation system to protect cookies in your local system, and it is job of the protocol to protect it while it is being delivered. So the best thing you can do is to use https, because nothing else is dependent upon you in the given configuration

Answer (score 0):

Let's summarize a few things here:

First of all, if your web application is configured correctly it is not possible to steal someone else's cookie. Unless you're on the same physical machine (which I assume is what you did with when you copied the cookie) of course.

So your site should always be served over HTTPS, that's configured correctly: `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`. And cookies should be HttpOnly (meaning not accessible by javascript): `options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;` (but that's for the session cookie). The cookie that is created by the Identity template is marked as HttpOnly and Secure by default so that's also fine. So basically the answer to your question is 'Yes, the Identity template is safe to use'

As a final comment I would recommend to add `app.UseHsts();` to add HSTS headers for more security.